# How to programatically set quicklook preview window size

Tags: plugins, size, preview, quicklook

I noticed that system plugins often adapt Quick Look preview window size to what is being previewed. I would like to implement similar behaviour in my .qlgenerator but I can't seem to find how this is done. I only found the initial static sizes defined in the info.plist file

Quick Look preview height
and
Quick Look preview width

Those two work and set the initial preview window size as expected but how do I set the sizes from within the program?

Comment: any news on this?? I'm with this same problem...

Comment: I am still stuck with this :-(

Comment: asked the same question myself and added a bounty. I hope I have an answer soon! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182887/set-windows-size-of-quicklook-plugin

Comment: Your question seems to be somewhat different. I /can/ change the values in the plist and the size changes accordingly but those values are static. I need to adapt to the content dynamically, every time and that's the question here...